# Getting callback is not a function in JS with Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts, callback

I am not being able to update min/max/avg values in Highcharts when doing zoom.
I am trying to combine these two pieces of code:

1.Update min/max/avg---->http://jsfiddle.net/d_paul/supgh9c1/4/

2.load DB tables based on zoom ---> https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/lazy-loading/

So the code shown here produce a "callback is not a function".
But if i remove the "e"(that is the event that highcharts pass when the user select a zoom) in the function after_Set_Extreme , I get "e" is not defined in that function. And if I add "e" as passing parameter (e,updateLegendLabel) I get same error as before, but now in the afterSetExtremes line. So it seems e(event) is not being recognized.
But if you see the link # 2 above, afterSetExtremes is called without passing "e", but is expected in the function . See function definition..
Can anyone help me to understand what is wrong here?

This is highcharts when doing the actual chart

```js
$('#container2').highcharts('StockChart', {
      chart: {
        zoomType: 'x',
        events: {
          load: updateLegendLabel
        }
      },
      ......

      xAxis: {
        events: {
          afterSetExtremes: after_Set_Extremes(updateLegendLabel),
        },
        .....


        function after_Set_Extremes(e, callback) {

          processed_json_temperatura.length = 0;
          processed_json_presion.length = 0;
          processed_json_humedad.length = 0;
          processed_json_lluvia.length = 0;
          processed_json_horas_frio.length = 0;

          if (typeof(e.rangeSelectorButton) !== 'undefined') {
            ........
            callback();
          }

          function updateLegendLabel() {
            var chrt = !this.chart ? this : this.chart;
            //  alert('entre updatelegend')
            console.log(this);
            chrt.update({
                  ....
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Combining these two functionalities seems to be very simple, please check this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/oh3ubdLv/

However, in your case `after_Set_Extremes` function is called only once, when the chart is initialized. You need to create an additional function to pass arguments:

```
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
    ...,
    xAxis: {
        events: {
            afterSetExtremes: function(e) {
                after_Set_Extremes(e, updateLegendLabel)
            }
        }
    }
});


function after_Set_Extremes(e, callback) {
    callback();
}

function updateLegendLabel() {
    console.log('callback');
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ebdtry20/